# gcc-11 compiler optimisation levels not working on Mac m1

Tags: c, gcc, apple-m1

I have to complete a project for university where I need to be able to optimise using compiler optimisation levels.
I am using OpenMP and as a result I have got the gcc-11 compiler from brew.
I have watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U161zVjv1rs and tried the same thing but I am getting an error:

```
gcc-11 -fopenmp jacobi2d1.c -o1 out/jacobi2d1
```

But I am getting the following error:

[image: Compiler optimisation error]

How do I do this?

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimization levels are specified with `-O1` etc, using capital letter O, not lower-case letter o.

Lower-case `-o1` specifies that the output file should be `1`, and then `out/jacobi2d1` is an input file to be linked, but it is an existing executable and you can't link one executable into another — hence the error from the linker.